# In a Telerik RadGrid user can't set the PageSize through textbox on the pager but can through dropdown

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik, telerik-grid

I've got a number of RadGrids in various pages but on one of them, a particularly big one, now when the user changes the Page Size via the Pager text field it doesn't keep that: when the grid finishes updating it's reset the Page Size back to whatever it was. If I change the PagerStyle.Mode so there's a dropdown shown instead of a text field then they can change it just fine. I can change it back & forth between `NextPrevNumericAndAdvanced` and `NextPrevAndNumeric`, and consistently it works with a dropdown (`NextPrevAndNumeric`) but not with a text field (`NextPrevNumericAndAdvanced`). If I modify the Page Size with the pager shown as a dropdown, then change the aspx to use a text field, then it locks the Page Size at whatever I selected in the dropdown.

What could it be that is causing this?

Comment: My guess would be your dropdown is `AutoPostBack=True` and the textbox has no postback events binded on it.

Comment: What triggers the postback when you use the text field? It'd be helpful if we saw some markup and the relevant portions of your codebehind (whatever event handler(s) update page size)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out the `if (!Page.IsPostBack) ...` had been removed from `Page_Load`, so on every postback it was resetting things. Putting this back resolved the problem.